# Pip error while installing tensorflow: no disk space

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, pip, python-3.8

I have been trying to install tensorflow on my system for python3.8 with pip3 v 20.1.1 ; Linux ( Ubuntu 20.04 LTS ). after the download is complete it returns error that there is not enough space:

```
Using cached tensorflow-2.2.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (516.3 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: google-pasta>=0.1.8 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.8.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from tensorflow) (3.12.2)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from tensorflow) (2.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: opt-einsum>=2.3.2 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from tensorflow) (3.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<2.0,>=1.16.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.18.4)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt>=1.11.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-estimator<2.3.0,>=2.2.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from tensorflow) (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py>=0.7.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.12.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from tensorflow) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py<2.11.0,>=2.10.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from tensorflow) (2.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: gast==0.3.3 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: astunparse==1.6.3 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-preprocessing>=1.1.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor>=1.1.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26; python_version >= "3" in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from tensorflow) (0.34.2)
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio>=1.8.6 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.29.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy==1.4.1; python_version >= "3" in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from protobuf>=3.8.0->tensorflow) (45.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth<2,>=1.6.3 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow) (1.16.1)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.15 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3,>=2.21.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown>=2.6.8 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow) (3.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard-plugin-wit>=1.6.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow) (1.6.0.post3)
Requirement already satisfied: rsa<4.1,>=3.1.4 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow) (4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow) (0.2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: cachetools<5.0,>=2.0.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow) (4.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.1.3 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from rsa<4.1,>=3.1.4->google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow) (0.4.8)
Requirement already satisfied: oauthlib>=3.0.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow) (3.1.0)
Installing collected packages: tensorflow
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

**I have 2GiB+ free space on all partitions except /srv, /boot and /boot/efi**

What do I do?

Comment: What partition is your home directory mounted on, and how much space does that partition have?

Comment: my /dev/sda3 is mounted to /home with a free disk space of 6.05GiB

Comment: How is `/tmp` mounted? Is it a separate partition? How much space does `/tmp` have?

Comment: Yes. /tmp is a seperate partition currently it has 2.73GiB unused space .

Comment: thank you @rayan-ral for the edit I am new to the forum so did not now how to format it properly.

Comment: Try rerunning with `pip install tensorflow -vvv` and see if it prints something new after the `Installing collected packages` line. Also, start `watch -n1 "du -sh /tmp"` in a separate terminal and monitor space allocation while installing.  `tensorflow` is pretty huge and will require something less than a 1GB unpacked in `/tmp`, plus the dependencies. My suspect is that the temp space gets full.

Comment: Yes, you were right. At the time of installation /tmp goes from 128k to full capacity. But I think it's only tensorflow, because before install it prompts that the requirement is satisfied for each dependancy. Is it normal for tensorflow to use nearly 3GiB of disk space at the time of installation? But I shall create a new partition with at least double the size an move tmp there. Hopefully it'll work fine after that.